# Want to Sort an array by ascending but Zero should be at Last

Tags: javascript

I am doing a php application for a sports event in some cases the minimum value scored is the winner. Like if there is 100mt running event then the winner is the fastest running. Winner has the minimum time taken to complete the race.

But what i am facing that when someone is absent or quit before finish then we are providing score ZERO. In that case when we are going to sort then the First Place will be the ZERO. But that should be at last.

Below is my code in javascript

```
var sorted = $(".result").sort(function (ib1, ib2) {
  return parseFloat($(ib2).val()) - parseFloat($(ib1).val());
});

// Result Names
$('#result_first').val($("#participant"+$(sorted.get(9)).data("section")).val());
$('#result_second').val($("#participant"+$(sorted.get(8)).data("section")).val());
$('#result_third').val($("#participant"+$(sorted.get(7)).data("section")).val());
$('#result_fourth').val($("#participant"+$(sorted.get(6)).data("section")).val());
$('#result_fifth').val($("#participant"+$(sorted.get(5)).data("section")).val());
$('#result_sixth').val($("#participant"+$(sorted.get(4)).data("section")).val());
$('#result_seventh').val($("#participant"+$(sorted.get(3)).data("section")).val());
$('#result_eighth').val($("#participant"+$(sorted.get(2)).data("section")).val());
$('#result_ninth').val($("#participant"+$(sorted.get(1)).data("section")).val());
$('#result_tenth').val($("#participant"+$(sorted.get(0)).data("section")).val());

// Result Numbers
$('#result_first_no').val($(sorted.get(9)).val());
$('#result_second_no').val($(sorted.get(8)).val());
$('#result_third_no').val($(sorted.get(7)).val());
$('#result_fourth_no').val($(sorted.get(6)).val());
$('#result_fifth_no').val($(sorted.get(5)).val());
$('#result_sixth_no').val($(sorted.get(4)).val());
$('#result_seventh_no').val($(sorted.get(3)).val());
$('#result_eighth_no').val($(sorted.get(2)).val());
$('#result_ninth_no').val($(sorted.get(1)).val());
$('#result_tenth_no').val($(sorted.get(0)).val());
```

Please help me to sort these values and the ZERO values should be last.

Comment: You really should use a loop after the sort. And stop to enumerate your elements with ids - just use one common class.

Comment: Can you show us your HTML markup, please? It looks like you're overusing jQuery a lot.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The basic idea here is to treat a `0` as `Infinity`:

```
var sorted = $(".result").sort(function (ib1, ib2) {
    function value(el) {
        var x = parseFloat($(el).val());
        return x === 0 ? Infinity : x;
    }

    return value(ib2) - value(ib1);
});
```

A simple test:

```js
var sorted = [5, 2, 0, 9, 4].sort(function(ib1, ib2) {
  function value(el) {
    var x = el; // parseFloat($(el).val());
    return x === 0 ? Infinity : x;
  }

  return value(ib2) - value(ib1);
});

console.log(sorted);
```

Comment: I like your solution as well.

Comment: *the ZERO values should be last* So should `value(ib2) - value(ib1)` not be `value(ib1) - value(ib2)`? Also you can try `function value(el){ return Number($(el).val()) || Infinity; }`.

Comment: I'd do it that way, but then the original code in the question would have to change to reverse the order currently used... (`sorted.get(9)`, `sorted.get(8)`, etc.) Basically, they're sorting descending but then manually reversing the result. This function should be able to drop in to the existing code and get the desired result, but yes, it would be better to just reverse everything.

Comment: @smarx thats a great point, but after properly reading OP's code, I'm more confused as to what is the objective. None the less, your answer address most of the solution. As an ads-on, we can also suggest creating an array with number as words and loop over it to update values. This will reduce redundant code. I'd leave it to you if you want to incorporate this in answer.

Comment: Same for php i have done sort using asort($in_progress_result); can you please tell the same how i will ignore zero @smarx

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".result").sort(function (ib1, ib2) {
    ib1 = parseFloat($(ib1).val()); ib2 = parseFloat($(ib2).val());
    return (ib1 * ib2 === 0) ? ((ib1 === ib2) ? (0) : ((ib1 === 0) ? -1 : 1)) : (ib2 - ib1);
});
```

If `ib1` is 0, then it is "greater" than `ib2`. Otherwise, if their product is 0 (so `ib2` is 0), then `ib1` is "smaller" than `ib2`. If none of them is 0, then your initial logic is applied.

Comment: This won't quite work as-is... you need to get the value of the elements first and then parse them as floats. (Here you're comparing HTML elements, and you're only attempting to parse them in one branch, and even then, you're not parsing the actual values.)

Comment: @smarx thank you, I will edit this answer accordingly.

Comment: If both values are 0, this code (assuming the fixes in my previous comment) always says the first value passed in is smaller. So if `a` and `b` are both zero, `f(a, b) === -1 && f(b, a) === -1`. I think any good `sort` implementation won't really be broken by this, since it won't ask both of those questions, but it's not a great idea.

Comment: @smarx thank you for the constructive criticism, it's morning here :)

Comment: $in_progress_result = array(
      $participant01 => $result01,
      $participant02 => $result02,
      $participant03 => $result03,
      $participant04 => $result04,
      $participant05 => $result05,
      $participant06 => $result06,
      $participant07 => $result07,
      $participant08 => $result08,
      $participant09 => $result09,
      $participant10 => $result10,
     );
    
    asort($in_progress_result);

Can you do it in this code which is in PHP @Lajos Arpad

Comment: @BinayakDas yes, if you have a function in PHP which compares $ib1 and $ib2, then the return line should be similar, but with the $ signs added. Instead of parseFloat you will need floatval. If you have a comparator, then using it in a cycle either directly or through a helper function should yield the expected result in PHP.

Comment: @BinayakDas such a helper function can be http://php.net/manual/ro/function.usort.php where you need to pass the comparator function I described in my previous comment. Read more in the docs: http://php.net/manual/ro/function.usort.php